# Finding $\lim_{k\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+e^{-kx}} \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+e^{-kx}} \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx$.

The limit inside the integral is $0$ for $x<0$ and $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ for $x>0$. If $x=0$ the limit is $\frac12$ but this shouldn't matter.

I'm studying to take a real analysis qual later this month. This problem is #2 from [here](https://math.illinois.edu/system/files/inline-files/comp540_may2017.pdf).

Comment: Can you share what have you done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\left|\frac{1}{1+e^{-kx}}\right|\le 1$ so that $\left|\frac{1}{1+e^{-kx}}\frac1{1+x^2}\le \frac1{1+x^2}\right|\le \frac1{1+x^2}$.  Inasmuch as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx$ converges, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+e^{-kx}}\frac1{1+x^2}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-kx}}\frac1{1+x^2}\right)\,dx$$

And you can finish now.

Comment: Happy New Year!

Comment: @copper.hat Hi Joe!  Happy New Year to you.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{1 \over 1 + \expo{-kx}}\,
{1 \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\overbrace{%
\pars{{1 \over 1 + \expo{-kx}} +
{1 \over 1 + \expo{kkx}}}}^{\ds{=\ 1}}\
{1 \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over 1 + x^{2}} = \bbx{\pi \over 2}
\end{align}